# How can I use jQuery to make an input readonly?

Tags: jquery

I have the following input:

```
  <input id="fieldName" name="fieldName" type="text" class="text_box" value="Firstname"/>
```

How can I use jQuery to make this element a read-only input without changing the element or its value?

Answer (score 304):

These days with jQuery 1.6.1 or above it is recommended that .prop() be used when setting boolean attributes/properties.

```
$("#fieldName").prop("readonly", true);
```

Comment: Note that `readonly` does not apply to all inputs. [HTML attribute: readonly](See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly). I attempted to create a `select` that would allow the options to be shown, but not an other option to be selected. This cannot be done with `readonly`.

Comment: The correct way to refer an element is to use its `id` and so I would rather use  `$("#id_fieldName").prop("readonly", true);` provided the `id` of the field **fieldName** is **id_fieldName**.

Answer (score 101):

simply add the following attribute

```
// for disabled i.e. cannot highlight value or change
disabled="disabled"

// for readonly i.e. can highlight value but not change
readonly="readonly"
```

jQuery to make the change to the element (substitute `disabled` for `readonly` in the following for setting `readonly` attribute).

```
$('#fieldName').attr("disabled","disabled")
```

or

```
$('#fieldName').attr("disabled", true)
```

**NOTE: As of jQuery 1.6, it is recommended to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). The above code will work exactly the same except substitute `.attr()` for `.prop()`.**

Comment: disabling a field isn't the same as making it not editable, right?  disabling it will make it also not submit

Comment: @Dave correct. Also readonly inputs can be focused, disabled inputs can't

Comment: also elements with read only are submited but elements with disabled are not submited !

Answer (score 83):

To make an input readonly use:

```
 $("#fieldName").attr('readonly','readonly');
```

to make it read/write use:

```
$("#fieldName").removeAttr('readonly');
```

adding the `disabled` attribute won't send the value with post.

Answer (score 14):

There are two attributes, namely `readonly` and `disabled`, that can make a semi-read-only input. But there is a tiny difference between them.

```
<input type="text" readonly />
<input type="text" disabled />
```

- The `readonly` attribute makes your input text disabled, and users are not able to change it anymore.
- Not only will the `disabled` attribute make your input-text **disabled**(unchangeable) but also **cannot it be submitted**.

jQuery approach (1):

```
$("#inputID").prop("readonly", true);
$("#inputID").prop("disabled", true);
```

jQuery approach (2):

```
$("#inputID").attr("readonly","readonly");
$("#inputID").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

JavaScript approach:

```
document.getElementById("inputID").readOnly = true;
document.getElementById("inputID").disabled = true;
```

PS `prop` introduced with `jQuery 1.6`.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this by simply marking it `disabled` or `enabled`.  You can use this code to do this:

```
//for disable
$('#fieldName').prop('disabled', true);

//for enable 
$('#fieldName').prop('disabled', false);
```

or

$('#fieldName').prop('readonly', true);

$('#fieldName').prop('readonly', false);

--- Its better to use prop instead of attr.

Comment: Disabled inputs do not get submitted on form post/get.

Answer (score 3):

Use this example to make text box ReadOnly or  Not.

```
<input type="textbox" class="txt" id="txt"/>
<input type="button" class="Btn_readOnly" value="Readonly" />
<input type="button" class="Btn_notreadOnly" value="Not Readonly" />

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
       ('.Btn_readOnly').click(function(){
           $("#txt").prop("readonly", true);
       });

       ('.Btn_notreadOnly').click(function(){
           $("#txt").prop("readonly", false);
       });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given -

```
<input name="foo" type="text" value="foo" readonly />
```

this works - (jquery 1.7.1)

```
$('input[name="foo"]').prop('readonly', true);
```

**tested with readonly and readOnly - both worked.**

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use atribute disabled:

```
<input disabled="disabled" id="fieldName" name="fieldName" type="text" class="text_box" />
```

Or just use label tag: ;)

```
<label>
```

Comment: The question said "With jQuery" (which implies it should be done dynamically) and "read-only" (which is different to disabled).

Answer (score -1):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head >
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="fieldName" name="fieldName" type="text" class="text_box" value="Firstname" />
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $('#fieldName').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it's meaningful to also add that

```
$('#fieldName').prop('readonly',false);
```

can be used as a toggle option..

Comment: I tried this with jQuery 3.3.1 and it simply adds a `readonly` attribute to the element, regardless of the value passed. So your example would wind up making the input field read-only, despite ostensibly setting the value to false.

Answer (score -1):

In JQuery 1.12.1, my application uses code:

`$('"#raisepay_id"')[0].readOnly=true;`

`$('"#raisepay_id"')[0].readOnly=false;`

and it works.

Answer (score -2):

The setReadOnly(state) is very useful for forms, we can set any field to setReadOnly(state) directly or from various condition.But I prefer to use readOnly for setting opacity to the selector otherwise the attr='disabled' also worked like the same way.

readOnly examples:

```
$('input').setReadOnly(true);
```

or through the various codition like

```
var same = this.checked;
$('input').setReadOnly(same);
```

here we are using the state boolean value to set and remove readonly attribute from the input depending on a checkbox click.

Comment: the above examples don't work - setReadOnly isn't a function built into jquery or any browsers

Answer (score -3):

In html

```
$('#raisepay_id').attr("readonly", true) 

$("#raisepay_id").prop("readonly",true);
```

in bootstrap

```
$('#raisepay_id').attr("disabled", true) 

$("#raisepay_id").prop("disabled",true);
```

JQuery is a changing library and sometimes they make regular improvements. .attr() is used to get attributes from the HTML tags, and while it is perfectly functional .prop() was added later to be more semantic and it works better with value-less attributes like 'checked' and 'selected'.

It is advised that if you are using a later version of JQuery you should use .prop() whenever possible.

Comment: I voted this down because it is nonsensical. It's all HTML, JavaScript, and Bootstrap uses jQuery so that fact is not even relevant. Additionally disabled and read only are two different things which work independent of whether or not Bootstrap is used.