# OnBlur Javascript Textbox validation

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox called txtMobile.text. It offers a list of items for a user to select from a auto suggestion box. This works great until a user goes back to the textbox after selecting the autosuggestion, they can change the text and it doesnt prevent them. Any ideas how i can only get the user to be able to only select items from the auto suggestion and not let them edit the selected text?

```
<script> 

                //var txtMobile
                var isItemSelected = false;

                //Handler for AutoCompleter OnClientItemSelected event
                function onItemSelected() {
                    isItemSelected = true;
                }

                //Handler for textbox blur event
                function checkItemSelected(txtMobile) {
                    if (!isItemSelected) {


                        alert("Please select item from the list only");

                        document.getElementById("form1").reset();
                        //txtMobile.focus();

                        

                    }
                }


    </script>
```

Comment: Why don't use the build in html select tag?

Comment: Hi John, I am afriad the data source for the list is from SQL and its a huge long list. So the Textbox auto suggestion picks up the first 2 characters of the text and suggests an entry based on that

Comment: You can give attribute ' readonly' to your textbox.  Then users will not be able to modify the content.

Comment: Hello T.Shah, Thank you. I have tried that but it stops the user entering in the 1st two characters to allow a match. It would be great if i knew how to make the textbox ReadOnly after the user has selected an item from the suggestion list. Any deas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362153/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-make-an-input-readonly/6408755 - This will help